# heterogeneous data logging and analysis

Tags: python, logging, numpy, matplotlib

I'm using python to prototype the algorithms of a computer vision system I'm creating. I would like to be able to easily log heterogeneous data, for example: images, numpy arrays, matplotlib plots, etc, from within the algorithms, and do that using two keys, one for the current frame number and another to describe the logged object. Then I would like to be able to browse all the data from a web browser. Finally, I would like to be able to easily process the logs to generate summaries, for example retrieve the key "points" for all the frame numbers and calculate some statistics on them. My intention is to use this logging subsystem to facilitate debugging the behaviour of the algorithms and produce summaries for benchmarking.

I'm set to create this subsystem myself but I thought to ask first if someone has already done something similar. Does anybody know of any python package that I can use to do what I ask?
otherwise, does anybody have any advice on which tools to use to create this myself?

Comment: I doubt that there are any off the shelf solutions, but it would be simple enough to set a small site with Flask, or another web framework that would display the data. You might also want to look into the Pandas package for data aggregation and processing.

Comment: There are plenty of tools out there to help create that type of framework, and it sounds like a really cool project.  Although I agree with @arun that there probably isn't an existing framework laid out for this. In addition to mongo, flask, etc.  There are other frameworks for message passing, NoSQL databases and threading.  My favorites are msgpack, redis and gevent (wsgi included) respectively.  Like reptilicus mentioned, Pandas would be very good for handling time sequences within the program logic.

Comment: Thanks for your comments. If I have to do it myself I think I'm going to keep it as simple as possible. I can see the value of learning to use some of the NoSQL databases suggested, but I just found "shelve" from the standard library, and it seems to do what I need regarding storage. It's basically a persistent dict. I could have a dict for frames and each frame contain a dict for all the heterogeneous data I want to save in each frame. For the web side, I was thinking to just generate static html pages, but maybe it would be worth the effort to learn Flask.

Comment: Hey! I just tested shelve and it works very well. I create a dict for all the heterogeneous data I want to store in every frame, then I store the dict in the shelve with key being the frame number and that's it. When I need to retrieve the information I just open the shelve and access the data. For example: `d= shelve.open('shelve_data') image = d['10']['plot'] points = d['11']['points']`

Comment: If you're going to build such a system, using a standard data format for this type of information, like HDF5, would work better for you, and also be much more useful to others, in the event that you'd like to share it.  There are tools for browsing HDF5 data, like HDFView, and ViTables, but none that are web based (as far as I know).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Another option for storage could be using hdf5 or pytables. Depending on how you structure the data, with pytables you can query the data at key "points". As noted in comments, I dont think an off the shelf solution exists.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I initially used shelve because I didn't need to learn anything new, it has the same interface as a dict. But the shelve can grow a lot (up to half a gig) and it becomes painfully slow even if I just use it to browse collected diagnose data. I see pytables promises to be fast (although I suspect harder to learn) I'll have a go.